# Opening a specific page of pdf in jquery using window.open(url) Browser issue

Tags: jquery

Facing issue opening a specific page of pdf in jquery using window.open(url) Browser

e.g.
url be like ***window.open(something/Mypdf.pdf#destinationname)*** 
works in Chrome but not in FF/IE
when url be like ***window.open(something/Mypdf.pdf#page=40)*** 
works fine in all browsers.

Please help me someone.

Answer (score 0):

After long research what I found is:

1. Google chrome no longer support NPAPI plugins.
2. It uses chrome pdf viewer to view pdf.
3. In other browsers which support Acrobat plugin,navigation to named destination is **possible** but requires one to set destination either using:

**a.** Adobe Acrobat pro/standard version as mentioned on their website or
**b.** Using third party destinator tool to convert bookmarks to named destinations.
Both of which are not free.
Also one must not confuse bookmarks with named destination.
The other option is to use pdfmark printfield  if pdf is created from word document.But have not tried it.